# R - determine if string can be eval'ed to a function without using eval()

Tags: r, string, eval

There seems to be a lot of functionality in R around `eval()` (at least more than I'm used to). Is there a way to test if a string (`str`) will evaluate to a function?

Looking for the follow functionality,

```
R> is.strFun("boo(x)")
TRUE
R> is.strFun("boo")
FALSE
R> is.strFun("boo(baz(Y))")
TRUE
```

I would rather not use the `eval(parse(text=str))` as that is what I'm currently using and it is getting very messy, as `"boo(x)"` may be `str` within `boo(x)`.

What I am trying to do: I would like to have R functions that are wrappers to another language.  But instead of the usual `eval2other('set x=2;set y=x*x')` (that is where a string in `other` language is evaluated to `other`), I would prefer the function to have a similar style to R. I have most of the parsing completed, but I run into trouble with thing like `"boo(boo(Y))"`. I have a solution, but it is really hairy and difficult to debug (even with packages like `debug`).

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  I just about **never** use `eval()` - it's just not necessary for almost anything you want to do in R. And I have certainly never found it necessary to use `eval(parse(..))`.

Comment: You don't mean "will evaluate to a function". "boo(x)" evaluates to whatever the "boo" function returns. In fact the only example you give that evaluates to a function is for the string "boo" itself (assuming there is a "boo" function).

Comment: What do you mean by "will evaluate to a function"? With `boo(x)` are you asking if when you call function `boo` with value `x` if it will return a function? Or with `boo(baz(Y))`, are you trying to test if both `boo` and `baz` are functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way that will work for prefix calls, but not for infix calls, such as `%in%`.

```
is.prefix.call <- function(text) {
    d <- getParseData(parse(text=text))
    with(d, token[id == 1] == 'SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL')
}

is.prefix.call("boo(x)")
# TRUE
is.prefix.call("boo")
# FALSE
is.prefix.call("boo(baz(Y))")
# TRUE
```

Comment: Didn't know about `getParseData`. This is exactly what I was looking for, and I think it solves a few more of my problems! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is far from perfect but it is short and maybe its good enough:

```
isFunCall <- function(x) grepl("[()]", x) & grepl("^[()[:alnum:]_.]+$", x)
isFunCall("a(b)")
## [1] TRUE
isFunCall("a(b(c))")
## [1] TRUE
isFunCall("d")
## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: But what about `isFunCall("x %in% y")`. :)

Comment: Using regular expressions is limited and obviously that and many other examples will not be handled but its not clear how comprehensive the solution needs to be.  If something simple that can distinguish between the examples shown is sufficient then this is only one line of code.

Comment: I was only joking.  :)  Filling my time while waiting for question clarification.

Comment: Sorry, missed the smiley.